# CSS Animated Checkmark

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want crate a animated Check-mark CSS(animating drawing of check mark with SVG animation), I tried like the following code but it does not work.what do I do?

**DEMO:** https://jsfiddle.net/b7Ln0jns/

CSS:

```
@import "bourbon";

$color--green: #7ac142;
$curve: cubic-bezier(0.650, 0.000, 0.450, 1.000);

.checkmark__circle {
  stroke-dasharray: 166;
  stroke-dashoffset: 166;
  stroke-width: 2;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
  stroke: $color--green;
  fill: none;
  animation: stroke .6s $curve forwards;
}

.checkmark {
  width: 56px;
  height: 56px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
  stroke-width: 2;
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
  margin: 10% auto;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px $color--green;
  animation: fill .4s ease-in-out .4s forwards, scale .3s ease-in-out .9s both;
}

.checkmark__check {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  stroke-dasharray: 48;
  stroke-dashoffset: 48;
  animation: stroke .3s $curve .8s forwards;
}

@keyframes stroke {
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes scale {
  0%, 100% {
    transform: none;
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1);
  }
}

@keyframes fill {
  100% {
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 30px $color--green;
  }
}
```

JS:

```
<svg class="checkmark" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 52 52"><circle class="checkmark__circle" cx="26" cy="26" r="25" fill="none"/><path class="checkmark__check" fill="none" d="M14.1 27.2l7.1 7.2 16.7-16.8"/></svg>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review our SO Question Checklist to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer. "does not work" is way to unclear. What did you do? What was the result? What do you expect?

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Since you are using a css file, you will need to convert the scss to css.

Here's a demo:

```css
.checkmark__circle {
  stroke-dasharray: 166;
  stroke-dashoffset: 166;
  stroke-width: 2;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
  stroke: #7ac142;
  fill: none;
  animation: stroke 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.65, 0, 0.45, 1) forwards;
}

.checkmark {
  width: 56px;
  height: 56px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
  stroke-width: 2;
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
  margin: 10% auto;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px #7ac142;
  animation: fill .4s ease-in-out .4s forwards, scale .3s ease-in-out .9s both;
}

.checkmark__check {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  stroke-dasharray: 48;
  stroke-dashoffset: 48;
  animation: stroke 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.65, 0, 0.45, 1) 0.8s forwards;
}

@keyframes stroke {
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes scale {
  0%, 100% {
    transform: none;
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1);
  }
}
@keyframes fill {
  100% {
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 30px #7ac142;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg class="checkmark" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 52 52">
  <circle class="checkmark__circle" cx="26" cy="26" r="25" fill="none"/>
  <path class="checkmark__check" fill="none" d="M14.1 27.2l7.1 7.2 16.7-16.8"/>
</svg>
```

SASS & SCSS Info:

Sass is an extension of CSS3, adding nested rules, variables, mixins, selector inheritance, and more. It’s translated to well-formatted, standard CSS using the command line tool or a web-framework plugin.

Sass has two syntaxes. The new main syntax (as of Sass 3) is known as “SCSS” (for “Sassy CSS”), and is a superset of CSS3’s syntax. This means that every valid CSS3 stylesheet is valid SCSS as well. SCSS files use the extension .scss.

The second, older syntax is known as the indented syntax (or just “Sass”). Inspired by Haml’s terseness, it’s intended for people who prefer conciseness over similarity to CSS. Instead of brackets and semicolons, it uses the indentation of lines to specify blocks. Although no longer the primary syntax, the indented syntax will continue to be supported. Files in the indented syntax use the extension .sass.

Comment: Your welcome!  If you are unfamiliar with scss, it might be a good idea to do some research on it.  I've updated my answer again which provides a little bit of info about both SASS and SCSS.

Comment: How can I enlarge this beautiful animation?

Comment: @Vingtoft,  please take a look at this demo for enlarging it:  https://jsfiddle.net/gtb1avet/1586/ -- This demo demonstrates enlarging it by 50px - via the CSS section, look for what is commented out: `/* ORIGINALLY ##px */`  -- Simply change the values where you see this comment to your liking - you can go smaller or larger :)  Hope this help!

Comment: how to resize it. lets say i want it to be 3-4 times as of now. Please suggest @Michael

Comment: @Pritam Jinal, look at my previous comment - it includes this link: https://jsfiddle.net/gtb1avet/1586/ -- You should be able to figure it out on how to enlarge and/or make it smaller from viewing the css code.

Comment: could you make an animation for a red X that shows that the user has entered something incorrect

Comment: Slightly updated fiddle with css vars for size control https://jsfiddle.net/hcxs4mao/

Comment: @buggedcom it doesn't work well in your update beyond 50px or I'm missing something?

Comment: @ThisGuy any luck you can make similar animation for red X and yellow ! warning ?

Comment: @Alexandre A., is this what you are after at least for the red X: https://jsfiddle.net/1taoqd9k/

Comment: Thank you @ThisGuy! I have used this checkmark a thousand times ^^